# iPhone keyboard with weird dot

Tags: iphone, ios6, keyboard, artifact

Where is this dot coming from?:
[image]

There is a dot hidden behind keyboard and highlights to blue when pressed (trying to press ?123) to change keyboard mode.

I have noticed it in few placed in my app and in iOS 6 (also with decimal keyboard, one can still see this dot which interferes with comma character).

There is nothing special I am doing with responders (normal `UITextView` of `UITextField` fields).
Anyone has idea what could be the cause of it?

Just to exclude popular cause: 
I have rootViewController of my key application `UIWindow` set to my root navigation controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the "old"(before iOS6) way to add a dot or return-key to `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad` but with a wrong keyboardType.

Something like in this tutorial: http://www.neoos.ch/blog/37-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key

Have you ever used this kind of custom keyboard in the past? Or maybe you don't know that you use it. Is there a category of UITextView you have overlooked?

Search through your project for e.g. "**@interface UITextField (**" to find the category.

Comment: Yep, old huge project, old, long forgotten piece of uncommented code.